# how do you test a try/catch inside use effect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

so I have this

```
    useEffect(() => {
        try {
            if (prop1 && prop2) {
                callThisFunction()
            } else {
                callThatFunction()
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error, 'the err:')
            setError(true)
        }
    }, [])
```

I want to get into the catch block to assert something, how can I do this?

currently I've tried mocking the implementation of one of the `callThis/That` functions and throwing an error to get it to go into the catch but that hasn't worked

updated: also tried this:

```
callThisFunction.mockImplementation(() => {
   throw Error(error)
})
```

I've got to the point it's jumping into the else but for some reason it wont then jump into the catch when the else fails. but the code works. just cant get the test too :/

any ideas?

Comment: @skyboyer added, is that what you mean?

Comment: @skyboyer doesn't even look like useEffect is being called :/

Comment: @skyboyer not sure you are understanding. i'm trying to jump into the catch block. so props wont make a difference, they will just jump into else block...

Comment: how do you test that? by chance is it Enzyme's `shallow()`? they(specifically, React's `shallowRenderer`) still does not support running `useEffect`. Have just tried short test with `useEffect` with enzyme/`mount()` and looks working. Add test code as well. PS yes, you're right, I misunderstood your question first, but now, I believe, get it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like:

```
export default function Example() {
        const [error, setError] = useState(false)
        async function asyncFetchAPI() {
            let response = null;
            try {
                response = await fetch('api/...')
                setError(false)
                const { prop1, prop2 } = response.data;
                if (prop1 && prop2) {
                    callThisFunction()
                } else {
                    callThatFunction()
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('The err: ', error)
                setError(true)
            }
        }

        useEffect(() => {
            asyncFetchAPI();
        }, []);

        return <div></div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use async function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async function() {
        try {
            if (prop1 && prop2) {
                callThisFunction()
            } else {
                callThatFunction()
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error, 'the err:')
            setError(true)
       }
    })();
}, [])
```

Comment: still not being called :/